# multiple websites on same domain

Tags: php, html

I'm currently working on two websites. I'd like for them to share the same domain and database. This way users would only have to make one account, and it could be used across both websites.

i.e. "www.mysite.com/option1/home.php" and "www.mysite.com/option2/home.php" would generate two different websites. But if you go to "www.mysite.com/home.php" it would give you an option to pick between websites.

My question is, is there anything wrong with this? Does the website load every page in each folder? (because this would probably slow it down)

Is this just a bad idea in general?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it and no php doesn't magically load everything in all directories unless you tell it to

Comment: @PeeHaa You should have put that in as an answer. Everyone else is, and getting upvoted for it too, which I have no idea why. lol I'm kidding of course ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its fine, as long you set your cookies per domain and not per path.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with that approach, it will work fine with no performance issues.

Answer (score -2):

No it doesn't load every page in every folder. If you look how the HTTP works, the browser get every resource needed to load the page One by one, but not less or more.

All will be ok if you do this, no extra loaded content!